# Draggable elements to stack into droppable container(bottom to top)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

When I drag my draggable elements (clones) into a droppable container, they stack from top to bottom, is there a way to invert that? I have tried adding a relative position to the parent element, and a "position:absolute;bottom:0" to the dragabble, but it doesn't work properly as then they all stay on the exact same position, so they don't stack on top of each other.

The code and a JSFiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/f3gzrtar/

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="containtment">

   <div class="cube">
  </div>

   <div class ="makeMeDroppable">
   </div>

  </div> <!--containtment-->
```

**CSS**:

```
.containtment {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid;
 }

 .cube {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 1%;
 }

 .cube.ui-draggable-dragging {
   background: green;
  }

 .draggableHelper {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: blue;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
  }

 .makeMeDroppable {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.cube').draggable({
  containment: "parent",
  cursor: 'move',
  helper: myHelper,
 })

 function myHelper() {
   return '<div class="draggableHelper"></div>';
 }

 $('.makeMeDroppable').droppable({
   drop: handleDropEvent
 });

 function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
   var draggable = ui.draggable;
 $(".makeMeDroppable").append("<div class='cube'></div>")
  }
 });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294487/jquery-ui-drag-drop-snap-to-bottom

Comment: There has to be a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401869/stacking-divs-from-bottom-to-top) you can use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: bottom` to stack divs from the bottom. Note that using `float: right` on the drop container means this won't work however. You need an additional surrounding element like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0hdus3v4/)

Alternatively you could use flexbox if you don't care about some older browsers by doing:

```
.makeMeDroppable {
  display: flex;
  float: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

[flex fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLc2ktd4/1/)

Comment: Funny, i was just looking at that answer, but I never thought about the float:right being the culprit for it not working. It works!